# Yii2 Parsing logger messages

Tags: yii2, yii2-log

I would like to get the logger messages and Parse them for email updates in a Human readable format.

I am currently using the logger and logging data to the DB and receiving emails by using the

```
Yii::info('test log','dashboard')
```

method.

My 2 classes in the config file are EmailTarget and DbTarget both with Categories set to 'dashboard' and levels set to 'info'.

All is working just fine as far as getting the data into the 2 targets.

The DB has 2 entries per trigger.  The first is the the message as above 'test log'. The second entry which is what I am most interested in has all the good data such as _GET, _POST and _SERVER, etc..

I have tried a few different way to get the data.

After triggering

```
Yii::info(...)
```

In one of the controllers the process the main page I called

```
Yii::getLogger()->messages
```

And I get the data from the bootstrap is seems with all the SQL startup queries.  No VARS or 'test logs'

I then tried a direct call

```
Yii::getLogger()->log('test log',0,'dashboard');
```

But then I get no logging but

```
Yii::getLogger()->messages
```

still provides startup data.

I did go into the DbTarget class and display the VARS I needed just not sure the path to that point, I hate to modify that class.

I thought of creating a custom Target however I am not sure how to do it after reading the section on it which is about 1 paragraph long.

I am just not sure how to 1. create a custom target or 2. how to intercept the VARS message.  I am guessing as the docs say the VARS are appended that this is processed internally.

I hope that all makes sense.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks
Scotty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own log target. Using `Yii::getLogger()->messages` is unreliable, because after each [`Logger::log()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-logger#log()-detail) call messages may be [flushed](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-logger#flush()-detail) to dispatcher, and as a result [`Logger::$messages`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-logger#$messages-detail) will be empty array. Depending on logger configuration, it may happen after each `log()` call, so `messages` will be always empty.

See also [`Logger::$flushInterval`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-logger#$flushInterval-detail) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for helping confirm my thoughts on needing to create my own target, I was having that suspicion.  Now I can shift my resources to that.